# Using Window.open when third party cookie is disabled does not return the value of postMessage

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

In our Google workspace add-on, we followed the example by https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/02/20/open-site-with-new-window-using-google-apps-script/ to open a third party URL in a new tab rather than in an iframe when the third party cookies are disabled.

Here is our implementation,

```
function openNewTab() {
var url = ‘third party URL’;
 var js = " \
    <script> \
      var windowRef = window.open('" + url +"'); \
      console.log(windowRef ); \
      window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false); \
      function handleMessage(e) { \
      console.log(e); \
      windowRef.top.window.close(); \
      }\
      console.log('Window ref'); \
    </script> \
     var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.');
}
```

What we are trying to achieve is that the third party URL communicates back via postMessage event, we are unable to capture it.  Is there something we are missing from the above implementation

Comment: What are you trying to get from the other website? Have you checked [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)? On the implementation you have it just opens the url in a new window.

Comment: @Kessy, We are opening a custom folder picker and after we select the folder, the folder picker provides the details where we can file the document from where we trigger the add-on.

Comment: And where is the issue? The `we are unable to capture it` means that the response does not get into apps script? Can you update on it ?

Comment: @Kessy, Yes.. The response is not captured on the appscript function.

window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of it? Also, why not using the drive Picker?